# Correct way to use div in while statement?

Tags: php, html, advanced-custom-fields

What is correct way to use `div` in `while`statement? I have problems figuring out - How to use `div` only once, while while loop is running.

**My current code ends up like this on every loop:**

```
 <div class="column1">
   <img src="IMG1">
</div>
<div class="column1">
   <img src="IMG">
</div>
```

**What I'm trying to achieve is -**

```
 <div class="column1">
   <img src="IMG1">
   <img src="IMG2">
</div>
```

My current code :

```
    <div class="roww"> 

    <?php if ( have_rows( 'image-collection' ) ) :

    $images = [];
    $i = 0;

    while ( have_rows( 'image-collection' ) ): the_row();

      $images[ $i ] = get_sub_field( 'image' );

      if ( get_sub_field( 'liela_bilde' ) == "True" ) { ?>

     <div class="column"> 
        <img src="<?php echo $images[ $i ][ 'url' ]; ?>" alt="<?php echo 
        $images[ $i ][ 'alt' ]; ?>">
    </div>

    <?php } else { ?>

    <div class="column1">
        <img src="<?php echo $images[ $i ][ 'url' ]; ?>" alt="<?php echo 
        $images[ $i ][ 'alt' ]; ?>">
    </div>


    <?php }?>
     <?php

     ++$i;

     endwhile;
     endif; ?>

     </div>
```

Comment: There is no "correct" or "wrong" way per se, it depends on what specifically you want to achieve. (Which is rather unclear as of now, so please describe that properly.)

Comment: If you have two records that you want to loop over, and have the output for both inside `column1`, then you obviously need to output that div _outside_ of the while loop.

Comment: Just use it one time? On a more serious notice - using and trying to create a self-written CMS is a bad idea if you are a beginner, and you code looks like an attempt to start writing your own CMS. I may be wrong, but i't very unclear what are you trying to achieve, what are you using(CMS? plain php?), etc.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin I forgot to add Wordpress  - Advanced custom fields .

Comment: So how does the `liela_bilde` play into this, what exactly do you want to output if that one is true? Is it only ever going to be one image in that case, or do you want to output multiple `column` divs in that case?

Comment: I've understood the problem, but can't check my solution right now. The `if ( get_sub_field( 'liela_bilde' ) == "True" )` can be dropper for now, or changed to something else. The main problem lies in the organization of `<div class="column">` and `<div class="column1"`. depending on the if statement they must be different, and there must be only one of them at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you may want to use div within PHP block inside while loop. If so, you can use below syntax for accomplishing the same.

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<div style='background-color:red;color:white;'>text</div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's a bit harder than that. As far as i know Wordpress `have_rows( 'image-collection' ) ): the_row()` will have to stay where it is.

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking and a little bit of testing, i think I got a womewhat workable solution. The key is that you have to take the `<div>` outside the while loop. Adding additional check `if($i==0)` you could do something like `echo 'class="column"'`.

My solution is probably the worst, that can be found, but it should work.

In the end your code should look something like:

```
<div class="roww"> 

<?php if ( have_rows( 'image-collection' ) ) :

        $images = [];
        $i = 0;

        ?> <div <?
        while ( have_rows( 'image-collection' ) ): the_row();

        $images[ $i ] = get_sub_field( 'image' );

        if ($i==0) {
            if ( get_sub_field( 'liela_bilde' ) == "True" ) { 
                echo 'class="column"';
            }
            else {
                echo 'class="column1"';
            }
        ?> > <? } ?>

        <img src="<?php echo $images[ $i ][ 'url' ]; ?>" alt="<?php echo 
        $images[ $i ][ 'alt' ]; ?>">

        <?php

        ++$i;

        endwhile; ?>
        </div> <?
    endif; ?>

</div>
```

This has not been tested, and may contain errors as did not have the time to try and replicate your structure. However, considering the fact that you are using Elliot's Condon plugin it **SHOULD** work, and you **SHOULD NOT** be getting broken HTML because of `<div`. If you do, then i made an error somewhere.

I also created a very simplified solution, that does not depend on plugins, can be adapded to suit your needs, and does what you desired. The code can be found below:

```
<div class="roww">

<?php 
    $test=true;

    if ( $test ) :

        $images = [];
        $i = 0;
        ?>
        <div 
        <?php
        while ( $test ) :

            $test1=true;

            if($i==0) { if($test1) echo 'class="column"'; else echo 'class="column1"';
            ?> > <? } ?>


            <img src="<?php echo "Yay"; ?>" alt="<?php echo 
            "Nay"; ?>">

            <?php
            ++$i;
            if($i==5) { break; }
        endwhile; ?>
        </div> <?php
    endif;
?>

</div>
```

It looks a bit different, but i tried to keep the main logic intact. By changing the values of `$test` and `$test1`, you could change the output of my example.

Comment: Also a note. My code is based on what i found on the official plugin page. It can be found here: [The Original](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I think what your are looking for is creating a row with X items and start a new row on that dynamic X?

In that case the answer can be found with %.

```
if ($myIndex % 2 === 0) {
  // Do something
}
```